# Is my bash script vulnerable to command injection?

Tags: bash, security, code-injection

I am in the process of QA'ing a fellow developers bash script.  It looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

TERM=`cat ./termName.txt` || exit $?
./other-script.sh $TERM
```

Given that the `TERM` variable isn't quoted in the last line, it feels like a malicious user could take advantage of command injection by manipulating the contents of `termName.txt`, however my basic attempts to prove this are failing to inject any executable commands.

My questions are:

1. Is this script vulnerable to command injection?
2. If yes, can you provide examples of how to execute arbitrary commands.  If no, can you explain why it is safe from command injection?

Comment: It won't run arbitrary code, but the value *is* subject to word-splitting and pathname expansion.

Comment: It is in my opinion, add this to your txt file `; echo "my injected command"`.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz `./other-script.sh` will just get 5 arguments `;`, `echo`, `"my`, `injected`, and `command"`. No code will be executed. The command line is parsed before `$TERM` is expanded.

Comment: @chepner `eval ./other-script.sh $TERM` would have been a different problem right?

Comment: @LuisMuñoz Yes, that's the dangerous command :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The script is not subject to command injection, because the expansion of `$TERM` only undergoes word-splitting and pathname expansion before the results are passed literally to `other-script.sh`. However, it *should* be quoted so that `other-script.sh` receives the *exact* contents of `TERM` as a single argument.

If `TERM` has the value `a b`, then `other-script` will receive *two* arguments, `a` and `b`, rather than one. Using `"$TERM"` passes the exact value `a b`.

If `TERM` has the value `*`, the exact list of arguments depends the contents of the current working directory. Using `"$TERM"` passes the exact value `*`.

Comment: Note that depending on what `other-script.sh` does with its arguments, wildcard expansion may constitute an information leak. An attacker could pass something like "/path/to/secret/dir/*", and if the results are visible (even indirectly) to the attacker they can use it to explore your directory structure. And if `other-script.sh` doesn't handle *its* variables correctly, it could always have vulnerabilities (including command injection) of its own.